# Making .NET REST API bulk upload faster without incurring SQL violation unique key

Tags: sql-server, rest, unique-constraint

I have a C# .NET 6 Web API using SQL Server database.  I have an API to **bulk upload** thousands of rows at a time. If I write the service layer to insert each row *one at a time*, it works, but it is *slow*.  It would be 3x faster if I call `db.SaveChanges()` only once per 200 rows.  (I tried it).

The problem is that when one record fails (for example Violation of UNIQUE KEY) then **all 200** records fail to insert.

I tried to check for key violations in advance (against the database and other records in the set of 200) and that works on `localhost`... but for some weird reason fails when I deploy it to Azure.

Is there any way to do this?  Do I have to choose between "fast" or "reliable"?

Comment: You need to include a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your code. We can't tell from that description what is actually going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a failed SaveChanges catch the DbUpdateException, and you can detach or correct the failed entities and try again.  SaveChanges() uses a transaction, so on failure none of the changes have been saved.

Note you may have to try multiple times, as typically only the first failure is returned to the client.